# python virtualenv is not being activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

OS: Lubuntu 16.04

I installed python virtual environment using: `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`
after that I created a new virtualenv using: `virtualenv -p python3 env3`

```
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /some_path/env3/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /some_path/env3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Then whenever I try to activate the environment, nothing happens!
I used: `./env3/bin/activate` and nothing happens after that.
I read that when an environment is activated it is added to the prompt to be something like:

`(environment_name) me@machine:/some_path$`

But nothing happens when I try to activate it. I thought it might just be something wrong with prompt GUI but when I try: `deactivate` the result is: `deactivate: command not found` which means the environment is not activated.
I also tried: `sudo ./env3/bin/activate` and `source /env3/bin/activate` but nothing worked :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `. env3/bin/activate` or `source env3/bin/activate`

```
➜  venv_example virtualenv -p python3 env3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/.../venv_example/env3/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /Users/.../venv_example/env3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

➜  venv_example ls
env3
➜  venv_example . env3/bin/activate
(env3) ➜  venv_example
```